# How to resample audio file using Tensorflow API

Tags: python, audio, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using tf.data.Dataset as pipeline in tensorflow to read and transform audio. 
I wanted to add audio resampling to reduce overfitting. I googled for a way to resample files in python/tensorflow and I found python only solutions like resampy. It works great but it slows down my pipline 10 times as I had to use tf.py_func to run it. My audio files are 1 second long with rate 16000, below is my code that does the resampling and then pads or clip the resulting array:

```
def _resample(pcm, label):
    if resample_range < 1e-8:
        return pcm, label

    import resampy
    desired_samples=16000
    def clip_o_pad(pcm):
        margin = pcm.shape[0] - desired_samples + 2
        if margin > 0:
            out = pcm[margin // 2: (pcm.shape[0] - margin // 2)]
        elif margin < 0:
            out = np.pad(clip, -margin // 2, 'constant', constant_values=(0))
        else:
            out = pcm
        return out[:desired_samples]

    def _resample_py(pcm):
        pcm = pcm.reshape(desired_samples)
        new_rate = np.random.randint(desired_samples*(1-resample_range), desired_samples*(1+resample_range))
        resampled = resampy.resample(pcm, desired_samples, new_rate)
        out = clip_o_pad(resampled)
        out = out.reshape(desired_samples,1)
        return out

    return tf.py_func(_resample_py, [pcm], pcm.dtype), label
```

Do you know about any library / function in tensorflow that would allow me to do the same in pure tensorflow graph (ie without using py_func)

Answer (score 3):

After some more googling I've noticed that tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio can do resampling.

However changing my pipline to use the procedure above did not improve the speed of my pipeline at all. Apparently the slowdown is caused by resampling not by the use of tf.py_func :/. Loading 200 examples takes 200ms without resampling, 5200 ms using resamply and py_func, and 5700 ms using ffmepg and pure tensorflow code.

In case anyone finds it useful the above code rewritten to tensorflow is below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def _decode_n_resample(data, label):
    min_rate = desired_samples * (1 - resample_range)
    max_rate = desired_samples * (1 - resample_range)
    if min_rate < max_rate:
        samples_per_second = tf.random_uniform([], min_rate, max_rate, dtype=tf.int32)
    else:
        samples_per_second = desired_samples
    pcm = tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio(data, file_format='wav', samples_per_second=samples_per_second,
                                         channel_count=1)


    number_of_samples = tf.shape(pcm)[0]
    samples_to_pad = desired_samples - number_of_samples

    padding = tf.cond(samples_to_pad > 0,
                      lambda : tf.to_int64([[tf.floor(samples_to_pad/2), tf.ceil(samples_to_pad/2)], [0, 0]]),
                      lambda : tf.to_int64([[0, 0], [0, 0]]))

    padded_pcm = tf.pad(
        pcm,
        padding,
        mode='CONSTANT')

    sliced_pcm = tf.slice(padded_pcm, [0, 0], [desired_samples, -1])

    return sliced_pcm, label
```

Comment: got an error: `TypeError: pred must not be a Python bool` on line 21 on your code around `padding = tf.cond(samples_to_pad > 0, ... etc.`

Comment: @OlegKokorin Aren't you running in eager execution mode? The tf.shape should return a tensor so the next operation should also be a tensor. If you aren't running in eager mode try to wrap desired_samples in to `tf.Constant` (that is rather a guess) the code was working fine in tf 1.4

Comment: tried to apply the algorithm to the real time audio resampling  application.